# Derivative of a lemniscate at the left hand side

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How does $${d \over{dx}}(3(x^2+y^2)^2)$$ turn into $$12y(x^2+y^2){{dy} \over{dx}}+12x(x^2+y^2)$$? I'm having a hard time solving it algebraically without it turning into a huge polynomial.

Comment: Use the chain rule then simplify

Comment: Write down the definition of total derivative and apply chain rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the chain rule.

$$3\left({d\over{dx}}(x^2+y^2)^2\right)=3\cdot2{d\over{dx}}(x^2+y^2)(x^2+y^2)=6\left(2x+2{d\over{dx}}(y)y\right)(x^2+y^2)=6\left(2x+2y{dy\over{dx}}\right)(x^2+y^2)=12(x^2+y^2)\left(y{dy\over{dx}}+x\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Sky, I see now that upon one part of the chair rule becoming a complete polynomial with a coefficient it can then be distributed amongst the single variables of y*dy/dx and x respectively without having to foil as if it were (2x+2x)*(x^2+y^2).

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Total derivative: ${df \over dx}={\partial f \over \partial x}{dx \over dx} + {\partial f \over \partial y}{dy \over dx}$ and ${dx \over dx }=1$

So,

$${d \over{dx}}3(x^2+y^2)^2 = {\partial \over \partial x}3(x^2+y^2)^2 + {\partial \over \partial y}3(x^2+y^2)^2 {dy \over dx} $$

You should be able to go from here.